# Append bash script content to another file

Tags: bash, shell, append

This is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

filenames="root/simulate/*.txt"
for f in "$filenames"; do
#append "#" to all .txt files
 sed -i -e 's/^/#/' $filenames
#append content of this bash script to all .txt files
 cat "$0" >> "$f"
done
```

But instead of appending its bash script content to all existing ".txt" files, it creates a new "*.txt" file in the directory and adds the content of the other ".txt" files into it, and then appends the bash script to that new file. Can anybody help? Thank you

Comment: Why are you running `sed` on `$filenames` every time through the loop, instead of `$f`?

Answer (score 1):

That is because `*` not expanding inside `""`, try it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in root/simulate/*.txt; do
    #append "#" to all .txt files
    sed -i -e 's/^/#/' "$f"
    #append content of this bash script to all .txt files
    cat "$0" >> "$f"
done
```

And you don't need a loop here, just this sed command:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i 's/^/#/;$r'"$0" root/simulate/*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use variable try

```
for f in $filenames; do
```